# Curly braces in a bash variable expands correctly, but the rsync isn't properly executing

Tags: command-line, bash, rsync

Why won't these braces work in a variable?

I have bash script with rsync with a --exclude option that calls a variable named EXCLUDE. That variable include literal curly braces.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eB

EXCLUDE="{'.env','.git*','*.log','config/ssh','/dev','node_modules','/web/app/uploads'}"

rsync -av --dry-run --exclude=$EXCLUDE web/ ${DEPLOY_USER}@${DEPLOY_HOSTNAME}:/sites/${DEPLOY_DOMAIN}/files/web
```

If I echo $EXCLUDE I get the correct string:

```bash
echo $EXCLUDE
{'.env','.git*','*.log','config/ssh','/dev','node_modules','/web/app/uploads'}
```

If I run the script without the EXCLUDE variable I get the expected results:

```bash
rsync -av --dry-run --exclude={'.env','.git*','*.log','config/ssh','/dev','node_modules','/web/app/uploads'} web/ username@123.456.789.0:/sites/xyz.org/files/web

building file list ... done
./
test.txt
```

However if I run the command with the EXCLUDE variable present the results are not correct:

```bash
rsync -av --dry-run --exclude=${EXCLUDE} web/ ${DEPLOY_USER}@${DEPLOY_HOSTNAME}:/sites/${DEPLOY_DOMAIN}/files/web

building file list ... done
./
node_modules
test.log
test.txt
```

Note that if I use `echo !!` to echo the last command that was run, the results are literally identical to the version without the $EXCLUDE variable:

```bash
echo !!
echo rsync -av --dry-run --exclude=$EXCLUDE web/ ${DEPLOY_USER}@${DEPLOY_HOSTNAME}:/sites/${DEPLOY_DOMAIN}/files/web
rsync -av --dry-run --exclude={'.env','.git*','*.log','config/ssh','/dev','node_modules','/web/app/uploads'} web/ username@123.456.789.0:/sites/xyz.org/files/web
```

I can even take the command that was returned by `echo !!`, run it, and get the expected results!

I've tried enclosing $EXCLUDE in curly braces, I've tried escaping the braces in the variable, I've tried `set -B` and with and without `-e`. Even though bash seems to be sending literally curly braces to rsync rsync is not evaluating the contents to the braces.

Why won't these braces work in a variable?

Comment: Brace expansion in bash happens before variable expansion.

Answer (score 2):

The command with curly braces works because the shell runs the brace expansion on it.

```
--exclude={'.env','.git*','*.log','config/ssh','/dev','node_modules','/web/app/uploads'}
```

becomes

```
--exclude=.env --exclude=.git* --exclude=*.log --exclude=config/ssh --exclude=/dev --exclude=node_modules --exclude=/web/app/uploads
```

Variable expansion happens later than brace expansion, so storing the braces in a variable doesn't work.

You can use an array instead:

```bash
excludes=(.env '.git*' '*.log' config/ssh /dev node_modules /web/app/uploads)
rsync -av --dry-run "${excludes[@]/#/--exclude=}" ...
```

The `${array[@]/#/PREPEND}` syntax is described in `man bash` under Parameter Expansion, it prepends PREPEND to the beginning of each member of the array.

Comment: Fascinating! I had no idea there were different kinds of brace expansion. I thought all braces were essentially arrays. Now I see they aren't really arrays at all. Bash continues to impress me.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK rsync itself only understands simple globs in the `--exclude` argument. So you're relying on the interactive shell to process the brace expansion.

That means `{'.env','.git*','*.log','config/ssh','/dev','node_modules','/web/app/uploads'}` **isn't** *"the correct string"* - you want the rsync command line to be passed with `--exclude='.env' --exclude='.git*' ...` already expanded.

You could use brace expansion *within an array*, and then expand the array within the rsync command:

```
EXCLUDE=(--exclude={'.env','.git*','*.log','config/ssh','/dev','node_modules',/web/app/uploads'})

rsync -av --dry-run "${EXCLUDE[@]}" web/ username@123.456.789.0:/sites/xyz.org/files/web
```

See also [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)

Comment: Wild! I'm presuming Bash is smart enough to not expand the variable assignment of `EXCLUDE={--exclude={'.env','.git*',...}` into `EXCLUDE='.env' EXCLUDE='.git*' EXCLUDE=...`?